# Where we do apply sigma rules in elk stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elk

Where we do apply sigma rules , is it in elastic search or kibana ? Where we can apply sigma rules for custom alert ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SigmaUI](https://github.com/socprime/SigmaUI) plugin to write, update and export Sigma rules straight from Kibana web UI